# Select2 con código compartido

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de ahorrar código insertando una función con el código que se repite en todas las variables, pero por alguna razón que no alcanzo a comprender no me funciona.

Este seria el código completo sin la función para repetir código.

```
$(".Series").select2({
 ajax: {
    url: "Select.php?que=Series",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
        return {
        q: params.term // search term
        };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
    return { results: data };
    },
    cache: false,
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    language: "es"
 }
});
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es cargar remotamente datos de json.

Y la idea es todo el código de ajax pasarlo a una función externa y pasarle la variable que quiero que cambie.

Algo tipo esto:

```
$(". Series").select2({ Busquiselect('Series'); });
```

y en la función Busquiselect meto el código que es común para todas.

```
function Busquiselect(Que) {
    ajax: {
    url: "Select.php?que="+Que,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
        return {
        q: params.term // search term
        };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
    return { results: data };
    },
    cache: false,
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    language: "es"
 }
};
```

El caso es que cuando lo ejecuto me da este error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected string literal 'Series'. Expected a parameter pattern or a ')' in parameter list.
```

No termino de entender donde esta el fallo de sintaxis, en otras funciones le paso parámetros usando las comillas y no dan fallo ¿por que puede estar dando el fallo aquí?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intentalo de esta forma:

```
$(". Series").select2( Busquiselect('Series') );
```

Y tu funcion:

```
function Busquiselect(Que) {
return {
    ajax: {
    url: "Select.php?que="+Que,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
        return {
        q: params.term // search term
        };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
    return { results: data };
    },
    cache: false,
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    language: "es"
    }
}
};
```

Comment: ¡¡Genial!! Ahora si funciona :) en cuanto pasen 5 minutos doy por aceptada la respuesta, que de momento no me deja... ¡¡Mil gracias!!

Comment: Para eso estamos @Killpe